# Float function always returning 0.000000

Tags: c, function, variables, floating-point, return

I'm a beginner with C and I can't find the solution for this "error" ...
(I don't want to just print what I read with scanf, that's just an extract from a bigger program, so can you try not to create a new code but to modify this ?)

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

float function(x){
    return x;
}

int main(){

    float x;
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("%f \n", function(x));

    return 0;
}
```

And if you don't mind ... can you explain the reason why it doesn't work in this way ? Thank you a lot

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: `float function(float x)` <-- mind the type.

Comment: For future reference, you could have demonstrated the problem using a constant value in your program rather than reading the value from stdin. For example: `float x = 0.1; printf("x = %f, function(x) = %f\n", x, function(x));` And show us the program's actual output (copy-and-paste it as code in the body of your question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined your function as:

```
float function(x){
    return x;
}
```

If you want the function to take a `float` argument, you need to say so:

```
float function(float x){
    return x;
}
```

Fixing that should fix your problem. You don't *really* need to worry about why your incorrect program behaves the way it does.

But if you're curious ...

Prior to the C99 standard, C had an "implicit `int`" rule. In this case, the parameter `x` would be of type `int` because you didn't specify its type explicitly. But since you used an old-style definition, not a prototype, you haven't told the compiler that the argument should be of type `int`. (Yes, old-style function declarations and definitions can cause some serious problems. That's why we have prototypes.)

So when you call your function with a `float` argument, the compiler doesn't complain, and it doesn't convert your argument from `float` to `int`. Instead, it promotes your argument from `float` to `double` (that's just one of the rules for calling a function with no visible prototype, or for calling a variadic function like `printf`), and the function itself *assumes* that you really passed it an `int`.

Result: The behavior is undefined.

One likely result is that the function will treat the `double` argument as if it were of type `int`, yielding garbage. Another is that it will read the `int` value from some other memory location or register, yielding even worse garbage.

Always enable warnings.  Always pay attention to any warnings your compiler produces.  Always ask your compiler to conform to the C99 or C11 standard unless you have a specific reason not to. And always declare and define your functions with prototypes.  (A *prototype* is a function declaration that specifies the types of the parameters.)

This also means that `int main()` should be `int main(void)`. That's not likely to matter (unless you call `main` recursively, which would be silly), but it's a good habit.

Comment: Note that the keyword `int` is still optional in many cases. E.G., you can write  `signed` for a type, even though the type name is formally `signed int`!

Comment: Thank you a lot for the complete explanation and for the correction, now everything works fine.

Comment: @MrLister: That has nothing to do with the old implicit `int` rule. `int`, `signed`, `signed int`, and `int signed` are all equally valid names for the type. `int` happens to be the one that's listed first in the standard. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

You never defined the type of the function's parameter `x`.  Without an explicit type, the type defaults to `int`.  As a result, the `float` that you pass to the function gets converted to an `int` and gets truncated.

Add the parameter type to the function definition.

```
float function(float x){
    return x;
}
```

Comment: The type defaults to `int` only in pre-C99 compilers, or compilers that don't fully enforce C99 or C11 rules. Recent versions of gcc, for example, would warn about the OP's code even without any extra warning options.

Comment: The argument is not converted to `int`. See my answer.

Comment: There is no argument conversion when calling a function with no prototype, other than the default argument promotions

Comment: Thank you a lot for the correction and for the explanation, that was the error and now everything works fine.